# Swift - Using UITableViewController to create sub-menus

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7, drilldown

I am developing a simple hybrid iOS app using Xcode 7 and Swift 2. I need to create submenus from my main menu.

My main menu uses a table view. Now I can create a second `UITableViewController` and load the sub menu within that and create a third `UITableViewController` to load another sub menu and so on.

But is there a better way by reusing my initial `UITableViewController`?

`UITableViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

And I am using a single `UIViewController` to show the final textual information.

[image]

Here is my Main Menu code:

class MainMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
// MARK: Properties

var mainMenu = [MainMenu]()
var Item1Menu = [MainMenu]()
var Item12Menu = [MainMenu]()
var selectedMenu: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load the sample data.
    loadMainMenu()
    loadItem1Menu()
    loadItem12Menu()

}

func loadMainMenu() {
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "menu-1")!
    let menuItem1 = MainMenu(name: "Item 1", photo: image1, url: "no-url", urlType: "subMenu")!

    let image2 = UIImage(named: "menu-2")!
    let menuItem2 = MainMenu(name: "Item 2", photo: image2, url: "our-services", urlType: "localURL")!

    let image3 = UIImage(named: "menu-3")!
    let menuItem3 = MainMenu(name: "Item 3", photo: image3, url: "http://www.google.com", urlType: "webURL")!

    let image4 = UIImage(named: "menu-1")!
    let menuItem4 = MainMenu(name: "Item 4", photo: image4, url: "our-info", urlType: "localURL")!

    let image5 = UIImage(named: "menu-2")!
    let menuItem5 = MainMenu(name: "Item 5", photo: image5, url: "http://www.bing.com", urlType: "webURL")!

    //mainMenu.removeAll()
    mainMenu += [menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3, menuItem4, menuItem5]
}

func loadItem1Menu() {
    let image = UIImage(named: "menu-1")!
    let menuItem1 = MainMenu(name: "Item 1.1", photo: image, url: "our-profile", urlType: "localURL")!

    let menuItem2 = MainMenu(name: "Item 1.2", photo: image, url: "no-url", urlType: "sub-menu")!

    let menuItem3 = MainMenu(name: "Item 1.3", photo: image, url: "our-history", urlType: "localURL")!

    //mainMenu.removeAll()
    Item1Menu += [menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3]
}

func loadItem12Menu() {
    let image = UIImage(named: "menu-1")!
    let menuItem1 = MainMenu(name: "Item 1.2.1", photo: image, url: "portfolio-1", urlType: "localURL")!

    let menuItem2 = MainMenu(name: "Item 1.2.2", photo: image, url: "portfolio-2", urlType: "localURL")!

    let menuItem3 = MainMenu(name: "Item 1.2.3", photo: image, url: "portfolio-3", urlType: "localURL")!

    //mainMenu.removeAll()
    Item12Menu += [menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3]
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mainMenu.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "MainMenuTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainMenuTableViewCell

    // Fetches the appropriate menu for the data source layout.
    let menu = mainMenu[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = menu.name
    cell.menuImageView.image = menu.photo

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var segueString:String
    selectedMenu = indexPath.row
    let urlType = mainMenu[selectedMenu].urlType

    if urlType == "subMenu" {

        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/38763630/1019454
        let vc = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as! MainMenuTableViewController

        vc.mainMenu = Item1Menu
        // then push or present view controller
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    } else {


        switch(mainMenu[selectedMenu].urlType){

        case "localURL":
            segueString = "ShowLocalWeb"
        default:
            segueString = "ShowWeb"
        }

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueString, sender: self)
    }
}


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    /*
    if segue.identifier == "ShowSubMenu" {
        let subMenuController = segue.destinationViewController as! SubMenuTableViewController
        subMenuController.subMenu = mainMenu[selectedMenu]
    }*/

    if segue.identifier == "ShowLocalWeb" {
        let localViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! LocalWebViewController
        localViewController.mainMenu = mainMenu[selectedMenu]
    }

    if segue.identifier == "ShowWeb" {
        let webViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController
        webViewController.mainMenu = mainMenu[selectedMenu]

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use same `UITableViewController` to show your menus. you have to only maintain your data dynamically. Can you show your code specifically for `delegate`, `dataSource` and the way you use/show the data?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: Actually you are all set to go. The only change you need is create an instance of `MainMenuTableViewController ` and assign `mainMenu` with your new menu.

Comment: I am really new to iOS, could you help me with a snippet for instantiation and how to assign? And where should i create it?

Comment: plz see the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: What do you mean by new menu here?
And what is secondViewController? Do i have to create a new file? If so then that defeats the purpose since i don't to create a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are all set to go. The only change you need is create an instance of `MainMenuTableViewController` and assign `mainMenu` with your new menu.

Example:

When you wish to show new menu.

```
let vc = MainMenuTableViewController()
vc.menu = <new menu here>
// then push or present view controller
self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**Response to Comment below:**

No, you dont have to create new file, but new instance of `MainMenuTableViewController`. You have to change the data part, in your case array that contains `menu`. `<new menu here>` refers to array of new menu items.

For this you have to [Decouple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) the data, which will be helpful.

**Edit:**

Instead of creating your `vc` in the above fashion you can try creating it from the storyboard. Please follow the steps:

1. In storyboard assign storyboard identifier to `MainMenuTableViewController` and instead of this line

`let vc = MainMenuTableViewController()`

use

```
let vc = (UIStoryboard(name: <your storyboard file name>, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(<storyboard identifier of MainMainMenuTableViewController>)
```

The reason I suspect is the line that i previously is unable find cell to create and hence crasing.

Comment: What do you mean by new menu here? And what is secondViewController? Do i have to create a new file? If so then that defeats the purpose since i don't want to create a new TableViewController for every new drill down level.

Comment: Thanks. i already created a new array and everything. But i still don't follow what secondViewController is, hence my first comment.

MainMenuTableViewController.swift:106:59: Use of unresolved identifier 'secondViewController'

Comment: Oh Sorry i did'nt realize its `vc` and not `secondViewController`. Corrected it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are no errors now. But i am new to Swift so need to figure how the new instance works and use the new array i loaded. i will post for more help once i figure that out. For now i have selected your approach among the 3 answers.

Comment: I updated the code in my question above. But it keeps crashing when i try to click on a menu that has a sub menu. `Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]`

Comment: Can you tell me why the above error occurs @Vivek Molkar based on my updated code.
Also [here is another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115637/drill-down-hierarchical-data-with-uitableview) incase my question was not clear enough

Comment: Can you add some description that came along with the crash? I think i understand the reason of crash, can you try the udpated code to create your `vc`

Comment: The syntax you provided in the updated code is not correct, i think the identifier should be in double quotes. Here is more description with the old vc code.
`Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UITableView.m:6540`
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MainMenuTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: Yes ofcourse identifier is a string. Should be in double quotes. Description confirms my doubt. Instantiate the vc with the code i updated and crash should be gone. Note anything in <> should be repla ed with appropriate variables or strings as they are in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vivek. The view now instantiates with new menu but is appended with old menu as well. I will see how to fix that. But you have now officially answered my question with an optimised answer. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easiest solution you should switch your datasource and call .reloadData() on the tableView.

Whether you will actually have a few objects which implement the datasource protocol and just switch between them or have an array of objects acting as your datasource and just switch content of this array is your decision and is more of a styling / architectural thing.

Comment: I am not using a collectionView

Comment: so i should use `.reloadData()` in my `viewDidLoad()` ?

Comment: No, not in view did load. In there you can setup the first menu. Then, when you select a cell you switch your datasource and call reloadData. If you want to go back, well you have to figure out a good way to do so, because the top back button won't do that for you out of the box.

This (as well as inserting cells as submenus - but that is difficult) will allow you to stay within one view controller. What Vivek Molkar said will work, however it will create a new controller and push it on a navigation stack with an animated transition.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it, but i created a new function and called reloadData() but it does not seem to work. I will have to read further on how to implement reloadData.

`loadSubMenu()
tblView.reloadData()`

Comment: It actually worked and appended the rows to the main menu so i did not notice. I will have to read further on how to implement reloadData correctly.
If this works properly and is efficient, i will update the post.

`loadSubMenu()
self.tblView.reloadData()`

I cannot figure Vivek's solution so i do not know how it works.

Comment: Thanks a ton so far Andrzej. Sorry i was using the same array hence the appending of data. It loads the new menu but it does not provide a back button. I would have to figure a good way to do that like you mentioned !! I will wait for Vivek to update his answer as well.

Comment: I can help you later today to set it up properly with navigation back working.

Comment: I added a back button and can get it to work but it does not look elegant.

`self.navigationController? .setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:true)
let backButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
backButton.addTarget(self, action: "methodCall:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
backButton.setTitle("Back", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
backButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
backButton.sizeToFit()
let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem`

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the question is right, I'm guessing you have a main menu and want to show submenus underneath them.

One way of doing this is by inserting and deleting rows. This way you can just reuse the same UITableViewController. So, on click of Item 2 a set of rows can be inserted to the tableView at that index populated with your submenu data.

You can use the functions insertRowsAtIndexPaths(*:withRowAnimation:) and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(*:withRowAnimation:) inside a block of call to tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() and update the tableView datasource to achieve this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems like something i could try. Although what happens when i hit back? Will it be taken care of automatically or i would have to note which menu i was at earlier and insert that again?

I will give it a try and see how it works. My main aim is to avoid using multiple `UITableViewController`

Comment: It will be handles by itself. You just need to make sure you're datasource is handled properly while deleting and adding rows. Let me know if you need any further help with the code part.

Comment: Thanks @anaghaajith27. But i found Vivek Molkar answer easier since i only had to add 3-4 lines of code. Creating an instance was actually much easier, i just did not understand how to do it from the storyboard.