# Swift - How to implement a defaultviewcontroller loop

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to create 2 different default view controllers that then get called and do their specified action depending on what was in the cell. Would you create the view controller in the main storyboard use an xib, etc?

Basically I have a xml file that I'm parsing and then creating table views for till I get to the last (details) page for the item. From my understanding it is better to use the same tableviewcontroller multiple times instead of creating 1 for each level. Am I supposed to be creating a segue loop?

There are checks currently in place to make sure I use the right segue.

Would you pefrom the segue with:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    segueLocation = hNTUL[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].locationLevel
    segueTitle = hNTUL[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].locationTitle
    if segueLocation == "TableView" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "defaultDetailSeague", sender: cell)
        let destinationVC = DefaultDetailViewController()
        destinationVC.detailTitle = segueTitle
    }
    if segueLocation == "DetailView" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "defaultTableSeague", sender: cell)
        let destinationVC = DefaultTableViewController()
        destinationVC.tableTitle = segueTitle
    }
}
```

It is also possible that I'm trying to go about this the wrong way.

I've also been searching for project examples but haven't found any that might guide me in the right direction.

Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for showing more code, but my answer, below, still stands. You need an implementation of `prepare(for:sender:)` and you don't have one. Please read, _carefully_, what I said in my answer.

Comment: Would this be what you are talking about?

`override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "LevelTwo" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                
                let controller = segue.destination as! LevelTwoTableViewController
                
                let mCaty = mainCat[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
                controller.selectedName = mCaty.mainCategoriesTitle
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Yes, just that sort of thing, though I do not think your test for `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` is going to work as you expect (I could be wrong about that).

Comment: You really should read tutorial about how to pass data with segue...I dont know why you would write like this

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically generate 2 different table views that have the same UI and features but different content? If so just pass a bool value to the next ViewController via segue and build the table from the appropriate data source.

Comment: It is something similar to this [Drill-down Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115637/drill-down-hierarchical-data-with-uitableview/15116543#15116543)

Answer (score 0):

If you call `performSegue`, you must *not* create a `destinationVC`; the segue creates it for you. To *configure* the destination view controller, implement `prepare(for:sender:)` and fetch the segue's `destination`, casting it down to a DefaultDetailViewController. Be sure to check that this is the right segue first!

Comment: I can only comment on the code you showed. As shown, it is wrong, and my answer tells you why.