# Swift - Drill down hierarchical data with UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to build an app to navigate a data hierarchy. I have been consulting this [Drill-down Hierarchical UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115637/drill-down-hierarchical-data-with-uitableview) page and don't really know how to implement the sort of node structure using xml to implement this. I'm trying to avoid creating 100s of tableviewscontrollers, etc. From my understanding so far I believe I need to use nodes. After I have drilled all the way down then I will need to use a different viewcontroller but I believe I understand how todo that.

Here is a mini example of my XML file. I can make changes to it if necessary to make stuff work.

```
<hnt>
    <face>
        <action id="1">
            <name>Occipitofrontalis</name>
            <type>data</type>
            <description>data</description>
        </action>
    </face>
    <temporoman>
        <mandibulardep>
            <action id="1">
                <name>Occipitofrontalis</name>
                <type>data</type>
                <description>data</description>
            </action>
            <action id="2">
                <name>Occipitofrontalis</name>
                <type>data</type>
                <description>data</description>
            </action>
        </mandibulardep>
    </temporoman>
</hnt>

<face>
</face>
```

I am using this code to parse my xml file. I'm not sure how to print a sample out.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "01 - MainCategories", withExtension: "xml") {
        if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: path) {
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    eName = elementName
    if elementName == "mainCat" {
        mainCategoriesTitle = String()
    }
}


func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "mainCat" {

        let mCat = MainCategories()
        mCat.mainCategoriesTitle = mainCategoriesTitle

        mainCat.append(mCat)
    }
}


func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        if eName == "title" {
            mainCategoriesTitle += data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you present a small representative sample of the  xml?  Have you parsed it yet?  Please show the structure emitted from the parse.

Comment: You can re-use the same view controller, and push it manually, if the structure is similar for each node.

Comment: @danh I have updated my question with some code and sample xml.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the parser hopes to generate a hierarchy of categories.  (I don't see anything matching in the xml sample, but I'll assume it's there).

First thing that's needed is a tree-structured `Category` object.  At it's simplest, this is an NSObject subclass that has a `name` and an array of children which -- importantly -- is an array of `Category`.

A class method on Category can do the xml parsing. The basic outline of parsing xml into a tree structure is:

- on start document, build the root. make it the current node.
- on start element, create a child.  set it's parent to the current node.  make the child the current node.
- on finding anything else (like characters), set properties on the current node.
- on end element, make the current node's parent the current node.
- on end document, you're done.

That tree is the tree that's being discussed in the other question.  The whole idea is only possible if you have a tree structure and a notion of the current node (or current category) being browsed.

Comment: Are you explaining what the parser is doing or what I need todo to access the data?

Comment: I'm explaining what your parser must do.  It must produce a hierarchical model.  I also explain what a hierarchical model must be (minimally):  An object with some data, like "name", and an array of children which are the same class as their parent.

Comment: If you can produce a hierarchical model from the xml, then you can use that model in the answer to the other question.  "node" in this context is just the current position in the model (a category) being browsed by the user.  The table view in that other question lists the children (child categories) of the current node.